# Can I have a default type value for an associated type family?

Tags: haskell, types, type-families

Consider this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

module Study where

class C a where
    type T a = r | r -> a
    pred :: T a -> Bool
    pred _ = True
```

I want to have a more meaningful default definition of `pred`, like this:

```
class C' a where
    ...
    pred' = not . null
```

*(I imagine a default* `T' a` *to be* `= [a]`*.)*

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [default signature](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=default#extension-DefaultSignatures).

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| class C a where
Prelude|   type T a = r | r -> a
Prelude|   pred :: T a -> Bool
Prelude|   default pred :: (T a ~ [a]) => T a -> Bool
Prelude|   pred = not . null
Prelude| :}
```

*(Thanks to @luqui.)* Note that, if you want to be able to write an empty `instance C Integer`, you should also provide a default for `T` by adding the line `type T a = [a]`.

Comment: Well, this kind of works. I still cannot write an empty `instance C Integer`. I have to specify the `type T Integer = [Integer]`. But at least I can omit the definition of `pred`.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov, if you want an empty instance, you can also provide a default for `T` by adding the line `type T a = [a]`.